# why alway generate file like npm-debug.log.(number)

Tags: node.js, npm

When i open my project folder, there is always have some file like:

```
npm-debug.log.1091914729
npm-debug.log.2654614748
npm-debug.log.xxxxxxxxxx
```

Can anyone tell me which tool generate these file, and how to prevent it

Answer (score 0):

you have to read it by opening it .
this kind of file are made because of some bug or i can say some error occurs when you run some command like npm install or some other .

if any error occurs it will display to you on bash and also save that error file as `npm-debug.log` and focus on this line that `.log` file are use for save logs of our application's activity.
and solution of your problem is don't worry about this you can delete that log file and next time try to solve error that come when you install any library with `npm`.

for more you may read from this link

https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/node-logging-basics/

https://www.loggly.com/blog/three-node-js-libraries-which-make-sophisticated-logging-simplers/

Thanks have a nice day.
Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with that today. Took me the whole day to figure it out but when you run `npm i` there should be some warnings about requirements not being met. Simply fix those requirements and it should fix your problem.